# How to draw a one-side dotted border

Tags: sketch-app

In Sketch I know how to draw a one-side border (using [shadows](https://sketchtalk.io/discussion/1098/possible-a-border-only-on-one-side-of-a-shape)) and I know how to draw dotted border. But what would be the most elegant way to draw an only-on-one-side dotted border?

One obvious way would be to draw a rectangle and then just put a dotted line over it. This also can be converted to a symbol and looks like a bearable solution. But I guess still it can be done better.

To give you idea what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, can you post an example?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I've updated question with a screenshot - hopefully it will be clearer this way

Answer (score 1):

No. We don't have any option in Sketch (version 51.2) to draw a one sided border. As you have mentioned, the only workaround is to draw a dotted line above the rectangle shape.